# Vue.js: Table heading width dependent on data cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I want header items to have automatically the same width as attributes in table below.

I tried to do some tricks with Flex, nothing works. Another solution is use percent width for each heading, but I know that's wrong approach.

```html
<template>
    <div class="product-list">
        <div class="product-list__header">
            <div class="heading" v-for="heading in headings" :key="heading.id">
                <p>{{ heading.text }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-list__content">
            <div class="row" v-for="prod in products" :key="prod.id">
                <div class="table-data" v-for="(value, key) in prod" :key="key">
                    <p>{{ value }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I expect result to look like this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doxXI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by bootstrap for [show table](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/),
You only need to [add script](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/) in index and you can use in Bootstrap,

Comment: Unfortunately in the contents of the table cell I have to be able to add other components so Your option is dropped